# perl regex match line or null

Tags: regex, perl, string, null

ive got trouble with this regex:

```
$line1 = "bla <bla> bla F=<> bla <> <gggg> bla lba"
$line2 = "bla <bla> bla F=<somethingineed> bla <> <gggg> bla lba"
```

How can i match with single regex what is between <> in `F=<>` or `F=<somethingineed>`
it can be null or some string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

something like this should work, it'll only match stuff following F=

```
/F=<([^>]*)>/
```